# Extended figure caption and accompanying "List of"

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to write an extended figure caption section, and wondered if I could get LaTeX to do most of the hard work for me.

Ideally, it would take the form of a function, let say `\extcaption`, that we could use within a float, like

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image-a.pdf}
\caption{Important things.}
\extcaption{Less important things.}
\label{fig:bigA}
\end{figure}
```

and that we could print with

```
\printextcaptions
```

and that would return

> Figure 1.1, page 2: Less important things.

Anyway to do it?
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}

\section{A section}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image-a.pdf}
\caption{Picture of a big A}
%\extcaption{This picture is magnificent}
\label{fig:bigA}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image-b.pdf}
\caption[This picture is horrible]{Picture of a big B}
%\extcaption{This picture is horrible.}
\label{fig:bigB}
\end{figure}

%\printextcaptions

\end{document}
```

The best result I got was by setting a new list with the `tocloft` package

```
\newlistof[section]{extfig}{efc}{Extended figure captions}
\newcommand{\extcaption}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{extfig}
\par\noindent\textbf{\theextfig #1}
\addcontentsline{efc}{extfig}{\protect\numberline{\theextfig}#1}\par}
\renewcommand{\theextfig}{}
```

But this prints a new chapter while I want nothing, it does not print the extended caption in the format the way I want, and does not read the label of the figure (or table) float, so I would have to set everything manually.

Comment: You can always write `\thefigure` instead of `\theextfig` to the file.

Comment: Where can I find `locloft`?

Comment: @cfr `tocloft` ? It can be obtained from ctan: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft

Comment: Oh, a typo. OK. `\makeatletter
\newwrite\@efcwrite
\immediate\openout\@efcwrite\jobname.efc
\newcommand\extcaption[1]{%
  \par\noindent\textbf{#1}%
  \protected@write\@efcwrite{}{\figurename{} \thefigure: #1\par}}
\makeatother
` Unfortunately, I don't know how to read it - only write it.

Comment: That is, I have only figured out how to write the things. I can't read them back. Sadly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following writes out ToC-like entries to a new `.efc` file and reads it in using `\printextcaptions`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}

\newcommand{\extcaption}[1]{% Write to .efc file
  \addcontentsline{efc}{extfig}{\thefigure, page~\thepage: #1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printextcaptions}{\@starttoc{efc}}% Read .efc file
\newcommand{\l@extfig}[2]{\noindent #1\par}% How each .efc entry is handled
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{A section}

\printextcaptions

\lipsum[1-50]

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \caption{Picture of a big A}
  \extcaption{This picture is magnificent}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \includegraphics{example-image-b}
  \caption[This picture is horrible]{Picture of a big B}
  \extcaption{This picture is horrible}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks ! Is there a way to write multiple-paragraphs in the extended caption ?

Comment: @HcN: The command `\addcontentsline` is defined using a `\def`, not `\long\def`, and therefore doesn't accept paragraphs. One can either copy the definition and define it as `\long\def` or `\newcommand`, or "hide" the paragraph breaks by using `\protect\endgraf`. No empty/blank line should be in your `\extcaption` argument, as these translate to an implicit `\par`, which is not allowed for `\def`-ed macros.

Comment: It is certainly worth at least trying to define an alternative `\addcontentsline`, but I cannot locate where the function is. Would you know where it is ? The `\protect\endgraf` works fine.

Comment: @HcN Look in `latex.ltx`. Probably.

Comment: @cfr Found it, and made something that essentially works. I asked another question for the remaining dodgy bits in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279516/automatically-protect-new-paragraph-in-extended-figure-caption