# Automatically "protect" new paragraph in extended figure caption

Tags: graphics, captions

(Final code [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279525/hypertarget-pointing-at-thefigure/279581#279581))

This is an extension for an extended figure caption function I requested in  [Extended figure caption and accompanying "List of"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279411/extended-figure-caption-and-accompanying-list-of)  .

The given solution worked, but I would like it to give the function the hability to handle multiple paragraphs. Hence, I duplicated the `\addtocontents` and `\contentsline` functions to respectivelly `\addefcline` and `\efcline`, differing only by the definition `\long\def` instead of `\def`, giving them the hability to handle multiple paragraphs.

As a result, it works fine, but in the current form I have to use `\protect` every new line I make in the `\extcaption{`. Is there a way to automatically protect all new paragraph ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

% Redefinition of \addcontentsline
\long\def\addefcline#1#2#3{%
  \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\efcline{#2}{#3}{\thepage}}}

% Redefinition of \contentsline
\makeatletter
\long\def\efcline#1{\csname l@#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

% Extended figure caption
\newcommand{\extcaption}[1]{% Write to .efc file
  \addefcline{efc}{extfig}{{\bfseries \protect\hyperlink{fig:\thefigure}{Figure \thefigure, page~\thepage:}} #1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printextcaptions}{\@starttoc{efc}}% Read .efc file
\newcommand{\l@extfig}[2]{\noindent #1 \vspace{\parskip} \par}% How each .efc entry is handled
\makeatother

\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image-a.pdf}
\caption{Picture of a big A}
\extcaption{The reasons why A is magnificent
\protect\begin{itemize}
\protect\item "A" like Awesome
\protect\item "A" like Amazing
\protect\end{itemize}
}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image-b.pdf}
\caption{Picture of a big B}
\extcaption{The reasons why B is awful
\protect\begin{itemize}
\protect\item "B" like Bad
\protect\item "B" like Banana
\protect\end{itemize}
}
\end{figure}

\section{Extended figure captions}
\printextcaptions
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd say `\unexpanded{\unexpanded{#1}}` instead of `#1` in the definition of `\extcaption`. However, no hyperlink is made, because no target is defined, but I think it's a different problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\unexpanded{\unexpanded{#1}}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

% Redefinition of \addcontentsline
\long\def\addefcline#1#2#3{%
  \addtocontents{#1}{\efcline{#2}{#3}{\thepage}}}

% Redefinition of \contentsline
\makeatletter
\long\def\efcline#1{\csname l@#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

% Extended figure caption
\newcommand{\extcaption}[1]{% Write to .efc file
  \addefcline{efc}{extfig}{{%
    \bfseries \protect\hyperlink{fig:\thefigure}{Figure \thefigure, page~\thepage:}} %
    \unexpanded{\unexpanded{#1}}%
  }%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printextcaptions}{\@starttoc{efc}}% Read .efc file
\newcommand{\l@extfig}[2]{\noindent #1 \vspace{\parskip} \par}% How each .efc entry is handled
\makeatother

\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image-a.pdf}
\caption{Picture of a big A}\hypertarget{fig:\thefigure}{}
\extcaption{The reasons why A is magnificent
\begin{itemize}
\item "A" like Awesome
\item "A" like Amazing
\end{itemize}
}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image-b.pdf}
\caption{Picture of a big B}\hypertarget{fig:\thefigure}{}
\extcaption{The reasons why B is awful
\begin{itemize}
\item "B" like Bad
\item "B" like Banana
\end{itemize}
}
\end{figure}

\section{Extended figure captions}
\printextcaptions
\end{document}
```

I added a couple of targets in order that the links work.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot indeed ! This is one good thing done. The last remaining point would be, is there a way to get the hyperlinks to point at the figure without having to define an hypertarget every time ? The problem with redefining `\contentsline` is that `hyperref` do not alter the other functions ... or should I start a new question ?