# Extended figure caption for table

Tags: floats, captions

I would like to extend again a bit further my extended figure caption to account for tables as well. Previous questions are

[Hypertarget pointing at \thefigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279525/hypertarget-pointing-at-thefigure)

[Automatically "protect" new paragraph in extended figure caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279516/automatically-protect-new-paragraph-in-extended-figure-caption)

What the macro does is, defining a command `\extcaption{Some extended information about the current figure}` to be placed into a figure float, whose content is written into a .efc file then  printed somewhere at the end of the document by a command `\printextcaption`.

To extend it to tables, I do not think I need to recall all the code as, essentially, I would need a function (called `\checkwhichfloat` in the MWE) that is able to detect in which float it is called, and return the appropriate counter and string.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\newcommand\efccounter{}
\newcommand\efctext{}

% \newcommand\checkwhichfloat{
% If figure
\renewcommand\efccounter{\thefigure}
\renewcommand\efctext{Figure}
% else if table
\renewcommand\efccounter{\thetable}
\renewcommand\efctext{Table}
%

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
%\checkwhichfloat
\caption{This is \efctext~\efccounter}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
%\checkwhichfloat
\caption{This is \efctext~\efccounter}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Usually `\@captype` contains the current floating environment name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Axel Sommerfeldt's comment, I managed a solution with the `pdftexcmds` package (And skimming up this website):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds} 

\newcommand\efccounter{} % Contains counter
\newcommand\efctext{} % Contains float env. string
% -------------------------------
\makeatletter
\newcommand\checkwhichfloat{
% If figure
\ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\@captype}{figure}=0
\renewcommand\efccounter{\thefigure}
\renewcommand\efctext{Figure}
% If table
\else\ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\@captype}{table}=0
\renewcommand\efccounter{\thetable}
\renewcommand\efctext{Table}
\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\checkwhichfloat
\caption{This is \efctext~\efccounter}

\end{figure}

\begin{table}

\checkwhichfloat
\caption{This is \efctext~\efccounter}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```